# Variáveis Fortran 77

Tags: fortran

Peguei um código em fortran 77 onde tem uma linha assim:

```
DATA ZERO/0D0/,HALF/0.5D0/,ONE/1D0/,TWO/2D0/,THREE/3D0/,FOUR/4D0/
```

Estou transponde ele para PHP. Gostaria de saber o que são D0 depois da atribuição dos valores?

Aqui -> ZERO/0**D0**/

Comment: [Boa sorte](https://web.stanford.edu/class/me200c/tutorial_77/14_data.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`DATA ZERO/0D0/,HALF/0.5D0/,ONE/1D0/,TWO/2D0/,THREE/3D0/,FOUR/4D0/`**

---

**1)** É uma **declaração concatenada em uma linha**, é a mesma coisa que **declarar uma a uma**:

---

```fortran
  ZERO  = 0D0
  HALF  = 0.5D0
  ONE   = 1D0
  TWO   = 2D0
  THREE = 3D0
  FOUR  = 4D0
```

---

**2)** Para variáveis **double precision:**

---

Para uma **declaração concatenada** do tipo **double precision**, use:

---

**<kbd>`DATA NOME_VARIÁVEL /VALOR/,OUTRO_NOME_VARIÁVEL/VALOR/,...`</kbd>**

```fortran
 DATA ZERO/0D0/,HALF/0.5D0/,ONE/1D0/,TWO/2D0/,THREE/3D0/,FOUR/4D0/
```

Veja mais em:

**[`Double Precision in Real Numbers`](http://www-classes.usc.edu/engr/ce/108/text/fbk01.htm)**

Um bom exemplo:

**[`Double Precision Real literals in Fortran are written in different variations:`](http://ngwww.ucar.edu/ngmath/fitgrid/example2.f.d.html)**